# Why is wet paper crinkly?

Tags: everyday-life, material-science

When I spill water on paper and then the paper dries/the water evaporates, the paper is extremely stiff and crinkly (makes noise when moved).

Why is this? I understand that water breaks hydrogen bonds in between cellulose fibers in paper making it easy to rip, but when it dries, why is it stronger?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question. Wetting leads to a collapse of the cellulose fiber network. When dried, the deformed, "squashed" fibers are in greater contact than they were pre-wetting, and hence give rise to a dense, stiff mesh. A more thorough discussion is in this paper:

["Why does paper get stronger as it dries?"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1369702110701644) Alvaro Tejado and Theo G.M.van de Ven, *Materials Today*, **13**, September 2010, Pages 42-49.